# How to increase the contrast of old TV shows using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, contrast

I have some old movies and their contrast levels appear low - the pictures are very soft. How can I increase the contrast of these movies using ffmpeg?
I tried

```
ffmpeg -vf "pp=al" -crf 24 -c:a aac -b:a 48k -ac 1 -movflags +faststart
```

but the movie is still very washed out.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are a lot of older improperly encoded video files that use the broadcast color value range of 16-235, but without flagging it as such.  Therefore, range is reduced.  Sometimes this happens multiple times.  Depending on the specific issue with your source material, you might be able to fix this by changing a flag in the container.  https://superuser.com/q/1405177/48624

Answer (score 1):

Add the `scale` video filter – it is not only for changing width and height of frames, but for changing the *sample range for YCbCr (luma/colors) components,* too.

(TV and analog video recorder had limited range 15-235, PC has full range 0-255.)

Use it in the form

```
scale=in_range=limited:out_range=full
```

or – which is the same:

```
scale=in_range=tv:out_range=pc
```

In your case use

```
-vf "pp=al,scale=in_range=limited:out_range=full"
```

or only the `scale` filter:

```
-vf "scale=in_range=limited:out_range=full"
```